# How to query the number of elements stored in a db.ListProperty in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The entity class is defined like:

```py
class Item(db.Model):
    list = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

What's the attribute or function to return the number of elements stored in a ListProperty, so that I can use something like

```html
{{ item.list.... }}
```

to display that in a html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a list so you can use len() on it.

```
total = len(item.list)
```

or if you are using jinja on your html you can use the count filter

```
{{ item.list|count }}
```